# Customization of Select input label in materialui

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I am customizing a select using the "styled" method:

```
const StyledSelect = styled(Select)`
  height: 2rem;
  color: #fff;
  border-color: #fff;

  & .${selectClasses.icon} {
    color: #fff;
  }

  & .${outlinedInputClasses.notchedOutline} {
    border-color: #fff;
  }
  &:hover .${outlinedInputClasses.notchedOutline} {
    border-color: #fff;
  }

  &.${outlinedInputClasses.focused} .${outlinedInputClasses.notchedOutline} 
  {
    border-color: #fff !important;
  }
`;

...

<FormControl fullWidth>
     <InputLabel id="primary-ticker-selector">Ticker</InputLabel>
     <StyledSelect
            labelId="primary-ticker-selector"
            id="primary-ticker-selector"
            value={primary_ticker}
            label="Ticker"
            onChange={handlePrimaryTickerChange}
          >
            {tickers_list.map((ticker, index) => {
                return <MenuItem value={index}>{ticker}</MenuItem>
             })} 
      </StyledSelect>
 </FormControl>
```

However, when I do that I get 2 issues:

1. the label, when it shrinks, goes back to the primary color instead of staying white
2. the label is not centered vertically anymore because I reduced the height of the Select.

I'm trying to solve these issues using only the styled method, I do not want to import @material/styles. And I can't find any reference on how to do that.

EDIT: I found the answer for 1), will write below, but for 2 that is a mystery.

```
const StyledInputLabel = styled(InputLabel)`
color: #fff;
&.${inputLabelClasses.shrink} {
    color: #fff;
}
`;
```

Comment: Take a look here to fix the first issue https://github.com/mui/material-ui/issues/13840

Comment: Thanks @YanaTrifonova but that solution is only when overriding the theme. I tried to created a "styled" InputLabel and change the color, doesnt work, and the shrink class doesnt seem accessible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Label component has a transform property set on it which places the text vertically. You will have to override it with some CSS properties. Try this:

```
<InputLabel
  id="primary-ticker-selector"
  style={{
    height: "2rem",
    display: "flex",
    alignItems: "center",
    transform: "unset",
    paddingLeft: "6px",
  }}
>
  Ticker
</InputLabel>
```

You can adjust it based on your requirements.